# Как в dev. tools браузеров (например firefox) на вкладке profiling понять почему тормозит страница?

Tags: javascript, html, css, браузер, css-animation

Есть сайт. При прокрутке страницы в некоторых местах страница подтормаживает (падает фпс), так же при взаимодействии с некоторыми элементами и в моменты некоторых анимаций тоже подтормаживает. Причем чем больше размер экрана тем больше падает фпс. В разных браузерах по разному подает фпс, например в хроме тормозов почти не заметно, а в мозиле очень тормозит. Про мобильные браузеры молчу.

Как найти и распознать из-за чего так происходит?
[image: скрин]

Comment: А пример сайта. И где что происходит?

Comment: @NeedHate   mathew_patella скайп, если есть желание помочь.

Comment: так ведь написано: "отрисовка", то есть отображение браузером элементов, может зависеть как от количества элементов которые нужно показать, так и от стилей к ним

Comment: В свежей статье на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/304934/ подробно разжёвывают repaint и reflow. Среди прочего там сказано, что _получение_ свойств offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight, scrollTop/Left/Width/Height, clientTop/Left/Width/Height, getComputedStyle(), и currentStyle приводит к вызову reflow и repaint. Если вы используете эти свойства, то могут быть тормоза.

Comment: @Вячеслав спасибо)

Comment: На здоровье, только хотелось бы знать, в чём реально была проблема и чем помог мой комментарий.

Comment: @Вячеслав вот как раз-таки я очень много где вызывал offsetWidth/offsetHeight. Прямо в циклах причем циклов было тоже не мало. Ну и получается что объекты (дивы), помещались из своего узла в корень body, потом для них анимация полета очень уже ресурсоемкая оказалась с этими рефлоу и репэинтами. Чем помог? Я просто почитав про все это переделал на трансформы)

Comment: Тогда можно ответ оформить для конкретно вашего случаю, чтобы другим было удобно искать.

Comment: раз падает число кадров в секунду, значит не успевает 1 раз за 16 (реально же враспоряжении имееется 10 миллисекунда) миллисекунд все просчитать для создания одного кадра. я далеко не спец в этом вопросе, но мне очень интересно разобраться в том КАК ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ДЕВТУЛС.  я встречал статьи Ильи Григорика и других спецов (он спец по оптимизации в гугле), в которых они эту тему затрагивает. только они на английском языке. вот, например, ссылка https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail?hl=en#animation-render-frames-every-16ms .

Comment: тут как раз и говорится про 16 миллисекунд.может быть, эта ссылка как-то поможет разобраться в этом деле. я не видел толкового описания гугловских девтулс. могли бы и нормально описать их на своем сайте.

Comment: вот еще один источник, где рассказывается про частоту кадров, анимацию... https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/3050/   на русском языке

Answer (score 2):

Надо помнить, что браузер однопоточный - все вычисляет последовательно. Тормозит - это значит, например, ты кнопку нажал, а реакции долго нет. Почему долго нет реакции? Потому, что браузер ЕЩЕ занят длинными расчетами в сложном скрипте, выполнение которого было запущено ДО того, как ты кнопку нажал. Ты кнопку нажал, и функция-обработчик ставится в ОЧЕРЕДЬ выполнения скриптов, причем, в очереди она ПЕРВАЯ ПОСЛЕ того, как выполнится твой сложный скрипт.

Чтобы такого не было, надо сложный скрипт разбить, например, сеттаймаутами на куски, чтобы получились "окна" в его выполнении. Если "куски" будут по 10мс, то можно говорить о том, что частота обновления в визуальной области браузера будет 60 гц (60 кадров в секунду). Но это проще сформулировать, чем сделать. Если скрипт сложный, например, простая с виду игра типа Пакмэна, где все очень ХИТРО связано, то надо потратить время (переписывать придется большой кусок игры, так как очень много связанных вещей нарушается при вводе таймеров в код), чтобы разбить выполнение длинных скриптов на куски.

Девтулс браузера позволяет увидеть, какой код за каким выполняется и какую длительность имеет. Позволяет оценить, насколько эффективно используются возможности браузера по просчетам - либо сложные расчеты выполняются в куче без "окон" (это плохо, тормозит игра - длительный расчет  + длительный простой), а потом длинный период простоя (idle), либо сложные расчеты разбиты на мелкие куски, которые таймерами разнесены по времени (это хорошо - короткие расчеты + короткие простои).

Comment: безусловно скажу спасибо за интересный рассказ.

Comment: это мой личный опыт (пока что небольшой). я далеко не спец - начал учиться программировать на джаваскрипте совсем недавно. лучше всего и ИНТЕРЕСНЕЕ, на мой взгляд, учиться программировать на написании игр. сам придумываешь алгоритмы, реализуешь, а потом сам же и играешь